# How to mock OpenCV camera using GMock, or how test method that use camera with GTest?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, googletest, googlemock

I have written a wrapper for OpenCV library. I create `Camera` class that allows to use hardware camera.

The tested method is sth like this:

```cpp
bool Camera::Open(int idx) {
  cam_ = cv::VideoCapture(idx)
  if (cam_.isOpened())
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

I want to test `Open()` method using GTest, but I don't want to test it with real physical camera. I think that the best way is to use GMock, but I really don't know how to mock camera.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an interface for the camera and a factory function:

```
class ICam {
    virtual bool isOpened() const = 0;
};

class ICamFactory {
    virtual std::unique_ptr<ICam> VideoCapture(int idx) = 0;
};
```

You're camera class is then constructed with a CamFactory which implements ICamFactory. In  your test you can create a MockCamFactory which returns a MockCam.  You can then set expectations on MockCamFactory and MockCam:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockCamFactory, VideoCapture(idx))
  .WillOnce(ReturnNew<MockCam>());
EXPECT_CALL(mockCam, isOpened())
  .WillOnce(Return(true));

ASSERT_TRUE(camera.IsOpen(idx));
```

Your real Cam class then wraps the calls to OpenCV.